# Calling AmazonS3Client.GetObjectAsync() on lambda function take too long (~5s) on the first invoke

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cold-start

I'm using S3 client in lambda function, this is my code:

```cs
public class SomeLambdaFunction
{
    public async Task<string> Handler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var client = new AmazonS3Client();
        // begin stop watch
        await client.GetObjectAsync("<bucket-name>", "<object-key>");
        //end stopwatch and see took ~5s
    }
}
```

when I deploy and invoke in the first time, it took ~5s to execute `client.GetObjectAsync`, when I run later (reuse lambda instance), it is complete instantly.

PS: I'm aware of cold start issue of lambda function, but I thought it happen before lambda's handler actually run, does cold start really happen inside lambda's handler?

Comment: The 'cold start' happens when the function is first invoked (and possibly later if the container is deleted by Lambda). So, it happens 'before' your Lambda handler is run. You might enjoy reading this series of articles: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: No, "cold start" is _everything_ that happens the first time a new Lambda execution environment runs, _including_ any initialization code that's in the handler. You can move your `new AmazonS3Client()` call out of the handler and into a static initializer, which will cause its time to be accounted as "initialization" rather than "duration", but it will take just as long to run the first time your function's invoked (unless you want to pay for provisioned concurrency).

Comment: However, I'm guessing your real problem is that you're not giving your Lambda enough memory, which also means that you're not giving it enough CPU. Increase to 2 GB and see what your cold start time looks like (it's still not going to be great -- probably around 1 second, but that's better than 5).